# PHP Most Efficient way to Convert a String with Commas Separating Values to an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, dynamic-arrays

I've done some searching around and most posts are using the php explode function to separate a string and store its values into an array.

I need an efficient way to convert:

```
$string = "45,34,65,57,45,23,26,72,73,56";
```

To an array, so I can access single values using `$array[3]`.

Is there a better method than explode?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative way? Why is `explode()` not sufficient? Do you have actual performance problems with this? What kind of data sizes do you have?

Comment: Been doing this with explode() since the dawn of time. Called split() in JavaScript, String.split() in C and Java. What's wrong with these functions / methods?

Comment: There is [`str_getcsv` to parse a CSV string into an array](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). Though for the string you show, it's overkill.

Comment: To anyone downvoting, it would be great if you would explain why you did so. He's simply asking a question about best practice, every programmer's favourite topic.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, well now I know what is

Comment: @Jordan the tooltip for the dv button already explains it: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - all three apply to this question.

Comment: First sentence shows research, question very clearly is asking about performance and best practices, and is useful for deepening understanding of one of the basic functions in PHP. Perhaps some clarity and disambiguation around the term "better" is deserved, but I don't see how you're arriving at your conclusion that it meets all 3 of the downvote stipulations.

Comment: @Jordan Claiming to have searched doesnt equal having researched. If you google for "parse csv string php" you already get `split` and `str_getcsv` for possible alternatives to explode. So why not list them in the question? Or even better, try and compare them and then point out anything unclear. Also, asking about performance with no context whatsoever is asking for nothing. It's irrelevant whether explode takes this µs or some other call takes that µs without context. It's all premature optimization. Also, see Pekkas comment for additional reasons why its unclear.

Comment: @Gordon I agree with everything that you've said, but I think that it's still important that Taylor and others see that there isn't really a reason to use other functions than explode, and it's unfair to assume that just because you managed to search for the golden phrase, that he was able to as well. Yes, it's a basic question for you and others, but that doesn't mean its answers don't provide value to the community as a whole. Just my thoughts...not trying to belabor the point here, and thank you for explaining the downvote.

Comment: And, yes i got downvoted for no reasons.  My understanding to having a 'better method' covers my development time too.  I could re-write the whole of php to make a new function that is better than PHP, but that's certainly NOT a better way to get the solution.  My point is, explode is already implemented for you, and it does everything you need, and its most likely be using techniques that this post covers as its underlying implementation.  So why downvote my answer?

Comment: @Jordan I'd agree to that if the OP would have come to that conclusion in the end, but if you look at the OP's comment below the accepted answer you will see that s/he actually announced s/he'll not be using explode. Granted, the code does what the OP is asking for about 6 times faster and is probably using less memory but its utterly meaningless for a single call because we are talking 0.0000x vs 0.0000y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$desiredPart = 3;

$num = strtok($string, ',');
$part = 1;

while ($part < $desiredPart && $num !== false) {
    $num = strtok(',');
    $part++;
}

echo $num;
```

This is probably the most efficient if you need to handle really long, and I mean ***really long***, strings. For anything of the size you have posted as example, use `explode`.

---

If your parts are all the same length, just do:

```
$desiredPart = 3;
$partLength = 2;
$num = substr($string, ($partLength + 1) * ($desiredPart - 1), $partLength);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The string I posted was just an example, in practice the string will be between 400-600 values long. Would it be better to use this function over explode for that length?

Comment: @Taylor how about you benchmark it to see if it makes a notable difference in the overall context of your application. It sounds like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @Taylor I'd say it's still not worth the more complicated code, unless you're doing this constantly on very limited hardware. I saw you mentioned that the values have a constant length. In that case some math and a `substr` are even better.

Comment: Thanks for the additional post. I actually have two strings - one with parts of equal length, the other with different lengths (the longer one). I will use both of these, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Explode is the fastest method of splitting a string into an array, since it is a naive string reader searching for a delimiter. There is no regex engine overhead involved in this like with split/preg_split/ereg, etc. The only way you could improve performance would be splitting hairs on a mouse's back, and that would be to single quote your string array so that it's not parsed for variables.

However, given the size of your example array, you could calculate pi to the number of decimal places equivalent to the value of each number in the array and still not even scratch the surface of a performance problem.

Comment: Thank you for the info- I have had no performance issues with explode I was just unaware it was the best method in most cases

Comment: You're welcome, and regardless of any downvotes you have, good for you for not just naively assuming you should use one function or another. Research and deep knowledge is a powerful thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression but that would be slower than `explode()`

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the parts is constant, you can check performance of the str_split method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: everyone's hating on my post! But this is what I need, all of the values are the same length

Comment: but if you did `str_split($string, 3)` the result will contain "45,", "34,", etc, 3 character strings with a comma at the end of each string.

Comment: just a wild guess since I can't test this right now, what if you forecefully try to parse this as a number, will the comma be ignored? because in some locales ',' is used as the decimal separator. try your luck :) and share it with us

Comment: I might, but would it be more efficient than explode()? ;-)

Comment: No, AFAIK any string parsing & type conversion methods are very costly. Overall perf will also depend on whether you want to use the parts of the arrays as numbers or strings itself. eg. $arr[3] == '45' or $arr[3] < 46

Answer (score 0):

The `explode()` method is quickest.

`preg_split()` is a more flexible alternative, but it's much slower.

Answer (score -1):

whats wrong with explode?

you could use regex / substring, but those are slow in both development / runtime.
best of all, explode is done for you.

Comment: regex is maybe slow compared to explode and when working with large datasets, but it is certainly not absolutely slow.

Comment: Hey, what's the down vote for?   
Explode is already implemented for you and its underlying implementation may  just as well be dependent upon regex, so if you regex again, you are regexing twice.  What's the downvote for?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but explode's underlying implementation is string parsing, not a regex engine.